# Heroku flask web app available with given HTTP referral

Tags: wordpress, heroku, iframe, plotly-dash, plotly.js

I have a python flask app deployed on Heroku (a plotly-dash app https://dash.plot.ly/deployment). I'd like to it to appear on a WordPress site. I can use iframe to embed the Heroku app, but I want the Heroku app only accessible on the WordPress site. I was thinking, is there any way to restrict the Heroku server's access via certain HTTP referral.

Any other potential solution is welcomed.

Comment: DId you find the answer to this by any chance?

Comment: @squidg Not really. The workaround was to deploy the app on a Digital Ocean server and that allows more flexibility on the settings. Than I assigned the Digital Ocean hosted site to a subdomain and set that not accessible from external IP addresses. So it will only be accessible through our WordPress server's IP address via iframe.
Tbh, I know basically nothing about backend stuff so I needed professional advice on this. Sorry that I cannot be much of a help